# agenda files are opened in buffers on startup and have formatting errors

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I am not quite sure if this is default behavior, but it seems that when I set `org-agenda-files`, all these files are opened in buffers on Emacs startup.

This would be okay-ish if that's necessary for agenda to function, but when I enter them, they exhibit a bunch of formatting errors, among which the most annoying is that all asterisks are visible on headlines:

[image]

But also src-blocks are rendered in plaintext until I scroll up and down a bit.
Everything resolves when I reload org-mode though.

Can anybody tell me why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: Agenda files are only opened on demand, the first time an agenda is created. They remain open after that to speed up regenerating the agenda. So they should *not* be open when you start Emacs unless you are creating an agenda in your init file. You can check for that with `emacs -q` which bypasses your init file. If you switch to the buffer of one of these files, what is the major mode? It sounds as if `font-lock` is not turned on on these buffers - or maybe it is slow/sluggish to apply font-locking? It's not quite clear.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I have since figured out the problem does not seem to be with org config at all, but rather with dashboard, which I also use and did not consider as the culprit.

Comment: Indeed, if you use the dashboard package and configure it to show upcoming agenda items (by configuring the  `dashboard-items` variable), then it will load the `org-agenda` files. I'm not sure why it would mess up the org files don't look right. Maybe you need to load dashboard after loading Org?

Comment: Probably: if it loads the file but Org mode is not loaded, then the files don't have font-lock set up properly. The `auto-mode-alist` *should* take care of that if it is properly set up, but loading `dashboard` after `org` is a good idea in any case.